# Connecting to an Oracle database using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

I am able to successfully connect to a SQLite database and access a particular table using the set of commands below:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, and_
from sqlalchemy.sql import select
from pandas import DataFrame 

db = create_engine('sqlite:///path\\database.db')
metadata = MetaData(db)
table = Table('table name', metadata, autoload=True)
```

I am able to fetch data from an Oracle database using [cx_Oracle](https://oracle.github.io/python-cx_Oracle/).

However, when I try to connect to an Oracle database in SQLAlchemy, I am getting the following error:

> NoSuchTableError: <table name>

I have used the following commands:

```
db = create_engine('oracle://username:password@hostname:1521/instance name', echo='debug')
md = MetaData(bind=db)
t = Table('table name', md, autoload=True, schema='schema name')
```

When I use the following command:

```
t= Table('table name', md, autoload=True, oracle_resolve_synonyms=True)
```

I get the following error:

> AssertionError: There are multiple tables visible to the schema, you must specify owner

Can you please explain where exactly I am going wrong?

Comment: Try passing `username."table name"` instead of `table name`. I guess there's another table with the same name in other schema, which is accessible by this user as well.

Answer (score 30):

You don't need to import cx_Oracle anymore. The newer version of the sqlalchemy module calls the function cx_Oracle.makedsn(). Have a look:

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine

DIALECT = 'oracle'
SQL_DRIVER = 'cx_oracle'
USERNAME = 'your_username' #enter your username
PASSWORD = 'your_password' #enter your password
HOST = 'subdomain.domain.tld' #enter the oracle db host url
PORT = 1521 # enter the oracle port number
SERVICE = 'your_oracle_service_name' # enter the oracle db service name
ENGINE_PATH_WIN_AUTH = DIALECT + '+' + SQL_DRIVER + '://' + USERNAME + ':' + PASSWORD +'@' + HOST + ':' + str(PORT) + '/?service_name=' + SERVICE

engine = create_engine(ENGINE_PATH_WIN_AUTH)


#test query
import pandas as pd
test_df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM global_name', engine)
```

Comment: Any idea why I keep getting errors such as: "NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:oracle.cx_oracle"?

Comment: @Konstantin Are you using a virtual environment?
I would install cx_oracle just to make sure:
`python -m pip install cx_Oracle --upgrade`

Comment: I'm having errors using this method.. is it something they've changed recently in oracle? In their blog, they only show a method in which you need the wallet.sso file..

Comment: @RicardoSampaio could you post the error message, please. And the oracle db version you try to access? I am currently working only with Athena and MS SQL. So i am not sure how to reproduce it but let me try.

Answer (score 17):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import cx_Oracle

host=hostname
port=port
sid='sid'
user='username'
password='password'
sid = cx_Oracle.makedsn(host, port, sid=sid)

cstr = 'oracle://{user}:{password}@{sid}'.format(
    user=user,
    password=password,
    sid=sid
)

engine =  create_engine(
    cstr,
    convert_unicode=False,
    pool_recycle=10,
    pool_size=50,
    echo=True
)

result = engine.execute('select * from TABLE')

for row in result:
    print row
```

This worked for me. A connection object can also be created like

```
conn = engine.connect()
conn.close()
```

which will enable to close the connection. This works even if you have a tunnel to your remote DB from your local port.

Comment: Instead of using connection string as in `cstr`, I would prefer to build it from `sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL("oracle", user, password, sid)`

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you have the Oracle client on your machine with a valid tnsnames.ora file, this works for me:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd 
engine = create_engine('oracle://myusername:mypassword@SID')
con = engine.connect()
outpt = con.execute("SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE")
df = pd.DataFrame(outpt.fetchall())
df.columns = outpt.keys()
print(df.head())
con.close()
```

Comment: There is no sqlalchemy requirement for connecting to Oracle with tnsnames.ora.  You can connect with LDAP, OUD, OID, etc just as easily.

Answer (score 3):

"... if you already have a connection string that works with cx_Oracle":

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import cx_Oracle

conn_factory = lambda: conn_factory = lambda: cx_Oracle.connect(user=dbuser, password=dbpass, dsn=dsn)

engine = create_engine(
    "oracle://", 
    creator=conn_factory
)

data = pd.read_sql("SELECT 1 FROM DUAL", engine)
```

https://gist.github.com/DGrady/7fb5c2214f247dcff2cb5dd99e231483?permalink_comment_id=4035380#gistcomment-4035380

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, when there is no `tnsnames.ora` file.

```
user = 'system'
pwd = 'oracle'
dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn(
    '192.168.1.105', 49161,
    # service_name='your_service_name_if_any'
)
ora_engine = create_engine(f'oracle+cx_oracle://{user}:{pwd}@{dsn}', echo=True)
ora_engine.connect()
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `oracledb` I first generate the DSN via the ConnectParams method. then I use that as the host with `SQLAlchemy`

```py
import oracledb
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL


def __get_dataframe(sql: str) -> DataFrame:
    cp = oracledb.ConnectParams(
        host="Server",
        port=1521,
        service_name="SID")

    connection_url = URL.create(
        "oracle+oracledb",
        host=cp.get_connect_string(),
        username="username",
        password="password",
    )
    with create_engine(connection_url).connect() as connection:
        data_frame = connection.execute(text(sql)).fetchall()

    return pd.DataFrame(data_frame)


results = __get_dataframe("SELECT 1 FROM DUAL")
```

Comment: Also see https://medium.com/gitconnected/using-python-oracledb-1-0-with-sqlalchemy-pandas-django-and-flask-5d84e910cb19 and https://medium.com/oracledevs/using-the-development-branch-of-sqlalchemy-2-0-with-python-oracledb-d6e89090899c

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slighty polished version of @mkarun2's answer.

Prerequisites:

- Install packages:

  > sudo apt install libaio1
- Download Oracle InstantClient library
- Make a symlink:

  > ln -s libclntsh.so.21.1 libclntsh.so
- Run the app like this:

  > export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=oracle-instantclient/instantclient_21_1 python main.py

Heres `main.py`:

```py
import cx_Oracle
import sqlalchemy as sa


# Use your config
username = 'username'
password = 'security'
hostname = 'localhost'
service_name = 'Xal' or None
port = '1521'


# Tell cx_Oracle where to find the libraries. Optional.
cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir='oracle-instantclient/instantclient_21_1')


# Connection string
oracle_connection_string_fmt = (
    'oracle+cx_oracle://{username}:{password}@' +
    cx_Oracle.makedsn('{hostname}', '{port}', service_name='{service_name}')
)
url = oracle_connection_string_fmt.format(
    username=username, password=password, 
    hostname=hostname, port=port, 
    service_name=service_name,
)

# Create SqlAlchemy Engine
engine: sa.engine.Engine = sa.create_engine(url, echo=True)
```

Here's how to make your first query:

```py
res: sa.engine.cursor.LegacyCursorResult = engine.execute("SELECT * FROM tablename")
for row in res:
    print(row)
```

notice that the query does not have `;` at the end ;)  Oracle does not like semicolons.