# Read ORCL table into Dask dataframe

Tags: python, oracle, pandas, dask

Using `cx_Oracle` connector to read into pandas df works fine, for e.g:

```
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle

conn_str = u'username/password@host:port/service_name'
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(conn_str)
tablequery="select * from largetable where rownum <= 5000000"
pd_df = pd.read_sql(tablequery, conn)
```

However trying to read this table into a Dask dataframe ...

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

sqlalchemy_uri_orcl = "oracle:////username:password@host:port//service_name"
```

uri from [here](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/config/%20%27/%27%20escaped%20because%20on%20Windows%2010) with escape characters for Windows 10 and:

```
dask_df = dd.read_sql_table(table = tablequery, uri = sqlalchemy_uri_orcl, index = "IDX")
```

dd call from [here](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.read_sql_table), generates the following errors:

```
Error message: DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
```

Without escaping the '/' in the uri, the error is slightly different:

```
NoSuchTableError:
```

Not sure exactly how to pass the cx_Oracle connector to the dask call, if required

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure your URI looks right. In [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28453545/connect-to-oracle-database-using-sqlalchemy) they use the following, which I imagine works with Dask also:

```
host=hostname
port=port
sid='sid'
user='username'
password='password'
sid = cx_Oracle.makedsn(host, port, sid=sid)

uri = 'oracle://{user}:{password}@{sid}'.format(
    user=user,
    password=password,
    sid=sid
)
```