# Connect oracle with flask python

Tags: python, database, oracle, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm currently writing an program using Flask python. But I can not connect my database with my program.
I'm use Oracle for database.

```
import os

from sqlalchemy import create_engine

from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URI"))

db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
```

This is the code what I'm using for it, please help me to connect my database.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43506439/995018 can help you

Comment: What about looking at Oracle's tutorial https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/cloud/apaas/python/python-oracle-accs/python-oracle-accs.html ?