# Accessing Oracle via SQLAlchemy's `create_engine()` requires more settings, is not it?

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy, anaconda, fastapi

I am developing an API by means of the FastAPI. It is intended to get an input, retrieving data from a database (Oracle), and providing a processed output.

Here is a function that executes queries with Oracle engine:

```py
from sqlalchemy import exc, create_engine, inspect

def db_connection_sqlalchemy(your_query):
    db_config = config['database'] # configurations from a yml-file
    
    try:
        engine = create_engine("{0}+{1}://{2}:{3}@{4}".format(db_config['dialect'] #'oracle',
                                                              db_config['sql_driver'] #'cx_oracle',
                                                              db_config['username'],
                                                              db_config['password'],
                                                              db_config['network_alias']),
                               max_identifier_length=30,
                               encoding="utf8")
        inspector = inspect(engine)
        conn = engine.connect()
        rows = conn.execute(your_query)
        rows = rows.fetchmany()
        result = [dict(row.items()) for row in rows]
        conn.close()
        return result

    except exc.SQLAlchemyError as e:
        error = str(e.__dict__['orig'])
        return error
```

It works okay. However, to set it up I faced several issues.

**Issue 1.** After installing the SQLAlchemy via `pip install SQLAlchemy`, I was encountering this error:

> NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin:
> sqlalchemy.dialects:oracle.cx_oracle

Even though I thought that *"I do not need to import cx_Oracle anymore"*, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28453545/connect-to-oracle-database-using-sqlalchemy/57693172#57693172). I decided to install `pip install cx_Oracle` and than I got a next problem

**Issue 2.** Every time when I tried to execute an SQL-query, I was seeing this error:

> "DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library:
> "C:\oracle\12.2.0\x86\bin\oci.dll is not the correct
> architecture". See
> https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html
> for help"

So, to overcome this problem, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56119490/cx-oracle-error-dpi-1047-cannot-locate-a-64-bit-oracle-client-library/64467018#64467018) helped me.

Actually everything works till now, but is it still possible to avoid those additional steps (installing cx-Oracle library, getting dll-files) when dealing with SQLAlchemy or these are typical pitfalls when working with the Oracle DB in a virtual environment?

I have a virtual environment via Anaconda and Python 3.7.10 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always install cx_Oracle separately - adding one word "cx_Oracle" to my `pip install` isn't a big deal.  Regarding the quoted wording: importing (in a running script) is different to installing (in a system).

You will always need to install Instant Client and set PATH to it, or call `cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir= r"c:\path_to_libraries")` in your code (see [here](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html#locating-the-oracle-client-libraries)).

When fetching a large number of rows, tune `arraysize` and `prefetchrows`, see [Tuning Fetch Performance](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tuning.html#tuning-fetch-performance).