# DPI-1047 while connecting to oracle database using python libraries sqlalchemy and oracledb

Tags: oracle, sqlalchemy, sqlmodel, python-oracledb

You are using SqlAlchemy and oracledb to connect to oracle database optionally SqlModel.
You may use code samples given in [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57693172/41782) and [following snippet](https://github.com/cjbj/python-oracledb-demos-2022/blob/main/6_sqlalchemy_connect.py), merged below:

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine

import sys
import oracledb
oracledb.version = "8.3.0"
sys.modules["cx_Oracle"] = oracledb

DIALECT = 'oracle'
SQL_DRIVER = 'cx_oracle'
USERNAME = 'your_username' #enter your username
PASSWORD = 'your_password' #enter your password
HOST = 'subdomain.domain.tld' #enter the oracle db host url
PORT = 1521 # enter the oracle port number
SERVICE = 'your_oracle_service_name' # enter the oracle db service name
ENGINE_PATH_WIN_AUTH = DIALECT + '+' + SQL_DRIVER + '://' + USERNAME + ':' + PASSWORD +'@' + HOST + ':' + str(PORT) + '/?service_name=' + SERVICE

engine = create_engine(ENGINE_PATH_WIN_AUTH)
```

But for some reasons, you are getting an EXCEPTION: (oracledb.exceptions.DatabaseError) DPY-4027.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is special characters in the password such as @.
You need to [escape special characters in the password as given in the sqlalchemy documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines.html#escaping-special-characters-such-as-signs-in-passwords)

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
import urllib.parse
DIALECT = 'oracle'
SQL_DRIVER = 'cx_oracle'
USERNAME = 'your_username' #enter your username
PASSWORD = urllib.parse.quote_plus('your_password') #enter your password to be encoded
HOST = 'subdomain.domain.tld' #enter the oracle db host url
PORT = 1521 # enter the oracle port number
SERVICE = 'your_oracle_service_name' # enter the oracle db service name
ENGINE_PATH_WIN_AUTH = DIALECT + '+' + SQL_DRIVER + '://' + USERNAME + ':' + PASSWORD +'@' + HOST + ':' + str(PORT) + '/?service_name=' + SERVICE
engine = create_engine(ENGINE_PATH_WIN_AUTH)
```

If you have special characters such as @ in your password.
Most important line is below:

```
PASSWORD = urllib.parse.quote_plus('your_password')
```

Above code snippet works without oracle instant client.

Answer (score 0):

With SQLAlchemy 2 you could connect in various ways such as this way which is useful when there are special characters in the password:

```
engine = create_engine(
    f'oracle+oracledb://:@',
    connect_args={
        "user": username,
        "password": password,
        "dsn": cs
    })
```

You don't need the `sys.modules["cx_Oracle"] = oracledb` lines when using SQLAlchemy 2 with python-oracledb.

See [Using SQLAlchemy 2.0 with python-oracledb for Oracle Database](https://medium.com/oracledevs/using-the-development-branch-of-sqlalchemy-2-0-with-python-oracledb-d6e89090899c).

Comment: Current SqlModel (Version: 0.0.7) works with SQLAlchemy (1.4.4). Above dictionary usage works with SQLAlchemy 1.4.4 with  sqlalchemy2-stubs but you need to encode passwords still.